# VS Code - No default Snippets available

Tags: visual-studio-code, default, code-snippets

I wanted to start using Visual Studio Code for programming Python but am currently confused by the fact, that I can't use any default snippets. There simply aren't any snippets.

[Insert Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p96Cw.png): [has 0 snippets stored!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hWcD.png)

I tried reinstalling the python extension of VSC but to no avail. I also tried googling for quite some time but couldn't find any result. I hope somebody has a suggestion on how to fix this.

Comment: they are removed in a recent version, you have to add them yourself by fetching them from the repository and store them as user snippets, search SO for `python snippets visual studio code`

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. Is it known why they decided to remove the snippets?

Comment: these SO answers mention the issue